# FE1.1s USB Hub "device not recognized"

Tags: pcb, kicad, usb-hub

I am trying to create a 4-port USB hub using a FE1.1s IC. When I plug the USB hub into my computer. I got the error "device not recognized" from my laptop. I have been trying to troubleshoot the problem. The first thing that I am looking at is the schematics. Shown first below. Perhaps someone sees something that I don't. Also, this is the datasheet for the IC chip: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2991/FE1.1s+Data+Sheet+(Rev.+1.0).pdf

I compared the schematics with other people's schematics for USB hubs with a FE1.1s IC.

I found these guys who seem to have successfully used the FE1.1s: https://www.retrocution.com/2020/01/15/easy-diy-tiny-usb-hub-for-raspberry-pi-projects/ and https://oshpark.com/shared_projects/cQOybiUe

I look at the layers of their PCB and the circuit for the hub and their circuit looks very similar but doesn't include LED status lights (Picture of PCB board layer shown below second)

I am thinking about trying out their circuit however I want insurance that it works if I do and I still want to know what is causing the problem on my first circuit.

Another thing I was wondering was if the problem was the PCB layout of my board. I wasn't mindful of the lengths of the data lines making sure they were the same because I didn't think it matter at such a small difference. Below is a picture of my PCB layout, the third. Once again perhaps someone sees something that I don't. In the picture below, I circled the part of the PCB that is the usb hub. PCB also contains a charging circuit for a lipo battery and a boost circuit that when switched would power a raspberry pi zero. The USB is isolated from the other circuits except for a 5v power with the boost circuit however that shouldn’t matter since the USB hub should work independently from the rest of the board and get power from the micro USB.

Please tell me what you think I would greatly appreciate feedback! Thank you!

[image: 1st]

[image: 2nd]

[image: 3rd]

[image: 4th]

Comment: You have D+ & D- on your upstream port J5 connected backwards. D+ should be connected to pin-16 (DPU) of your FE1.1s and D- to pin-15 (DMU).

Comment: Hi brhans,
Thank you for pointing that out! I going to try to switch that on my PCB board right now.

Comment: Hi brhans,
Thank you so much for pointing that out! My USB hub works now!